# Where string data is stored?

Tags: c, linux, string, assembly, x86

I wrote a small c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "Hello, world!";
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0; 
}
```

which compiles to (on my linux machine):

```
    .file   "hello.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    $1819043144, -32(%rbp)
    movl    $1998597231, -28(%rbp)
    movl    $1684828783, -24(%rbp)
    movw    $33, -20(%rbp)
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    puts
    movl    $0, %eax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
    xorq    %fs:40, %rdx
    je  .L3
    call    __stack_chk_fail
.L3:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I don't understand the assembly code, but I can't see anywhere the string message. So how the executable know what to print?

Comment: The string is a constant in the memory, it should even be visible if you open your binary with an editor; the data is then copied into your array through movl visible in your disassembly.

Comment: Use the `strings` command on your ELF executable file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's here:

```
movl    $1819043144, -32(%rbp) ; 1819043144 = 0x6C6C6548 = "lleH"
movl    $1998597231, -28(%rbp) ; 1998597231 = 0x77202C6F = "w ,o"
movl    $1684828783, -24(%rbp) ; 1684828783 = 0x646C726F = "dlro"
movw    $33, -20(%rbp)         ;         33 =     0x0021 = "\0!"
```

In this particular case the compiler is generating inline instructions to generate the literal string constant before calling `printf`. Of course in other situations it may not do this but may instead store a string constant in another section of memory. Bottom line: you can not make any assumptions about how or where the compiler will generate and store string literals.

Comment: Why if I give a longer string, it shows in plain text, like: .string "a very long string"?

Comment: The exception is with pointers to literals, as these have to be arrays. I've added details in a separate answer.

Comment: Note, this isn't actually a 'string literal' in the C code, it's a local array of char with an initializer, which the compiler chose to inline. Much of what applies to string literals doesn't apply here. For instance, the function may set s[0] = 'J' without the usual concern about modifying 'other' strings. If you write, e.g.  char const *s = "Hello World", you now have a string literal and you will always see the bytes in the disassembly.

Comment: I.e. it's just shorthand for  char s[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', /*etc*/};

Answer (score 3):

The string is here:

```
movl    $1819043144, -32(%rbp)
movl    $1998597231, -28(%rbp)
movl    $1684828783, -24(%rbp)
```

This copies a bunch of values to the stack. Those values happen to be your string.

Answer (score 1):

string *constants* are stored in the binary of your application. Exactly where is up to your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Assembly has no "string" concept. Thus, the "string" is actually a chunk of memory. The string is stored somewhere in memory (up to the compiler) then you can manipulate this chunk of data using its memory address (pointer).

If your string is **constant**, compiler *might* want to use it as constants instead of storing it into memory, which is faster. This is your case, as pointed out by Paul R:

```
movl    $1819043144, -32(%rbp)
movl    $1998597231, -28(%rbp)
movl    $1684828783, -24(%rbp)
```

You cannot make assumptions about how the compiler will treat your string.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, the compiler can see that your string literal cannot be referenced directly (i.e. there can't be any valid pointers to your string), which is why it can just copy it inline. If however you assign a character pointer instead, i.e.

`char *s = "Hello, world!";`

The compiler will initialise a string literal somewhere in memory, since you can of course now point to it. This modification produces on my machine:

```
.LC0:
    .string "Hello, world!"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
```

One assumption can be made about string literals: if a pointer is initialised to a literal, it will point to a static char array held somewhere in memory. As a result the pointer is valid in any part of the program, e.g. you can return a pointer to a string literal initialised in a function, and it will still be valid.